# Python: most efficient way to categorize transactions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a large list of transactions that I want to categorize.
It looks like this:

```
transactions: [
     {
        "id": "20200117-16045-0",
        "date": "2020-01-17",
        "creationTime": null,
        "text": "SuperB Vesterbro T 74637",
        "originalText": "SuperB Vesterbro T 74637",
        "details": null,
        "category": null,
        "amount": {
            "value": -160.45,
            "currency": "DKK"
        },
        "balance": {
            "value": 12572.68,
            "currency": "DKK"
        },
        "type": "Card",
        "state": "Booked"
    },
    {
        "id": "20200117-4800-0",
        "date": "2020-01-17",
        "creationTime": null,
        "text": "Rent        45228",
        "originalText": "Rent        45228",
        "details": null,
        "category": null,
        "amount": {
            "value": -48.00,
            "currency": "DKK"
        },
        "balance": {
            "value": 12733.13,
            "currency": "DKK"
        },
        "type": "Card",
        "state": "Booked"
    },
    {
        "id": "20200114-1200-0",
        "date": "2020-01-14",
        "creationTime": null,
        "text": "Superbest          86125",
        "originalText": "SUPERBEST          86125",
        "details": null,
        "category": null,
        "amount": {
            "value": -12.00,
            "currency": "DKK"
        },
        "balance": {
            "value": 12781.13,
            "currency": "DKK"
        },
        "type": "Card",
        "state": "Booked"
    }
]
```

I loaded in the data like this:

```
with open('transactions.json') as transactions:
    file = json.load(transactions)

data = json_normalize(file)['transactions'][0]
return pd.DataFrame(data)
```

And I have the following categories so far, I want to group the transactions by:

```
CATEGORIES = {
    'Groceries': ['SuperB', 'Superbest'],
    'Housing': ['Insurance', 'Rent']
}
```

Now I would like to loop through each row in the DataFrame and group each transaction.
I would like to do this, by checking if `text` contains one of the values from the `CATEGORIES` dictionary.

If so, that transaction should get categorized as the key of the `CATEGORIES` dictionary - for instance `Groceries`.

How do I do this most efficiently?

Comment: Before worrying about efficiency, do you have a solution that works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly.

we can create a pipe delimited list from your dictionary and do some assignment with `.loc`

```
print(df)
for k,v in CATEGORIES.items():
    pat = '|'.join(v)
    df.loc[df['text'].str.contains(pat),'category'] = k
print(df[['text','category']])
                       text   category
0  SuperB Vesterbro T 74637  Groceries
1         Rent        45228    Housing
2  Superbest          86125  Groceries
```

---

more efficient solution :

we create a single list of all your values and extract them with `str.extract` at the same time we re-create your dictionary, so each value is now the key we will map onto your target DataFrame.

```
words = []
mapping_dict = {}
for k,v in CATEGORIES.items():
    for item in v:
        words.append(item)
        mapping_dict[item] = k


ext = df['text'].str.extract(f"({'|'.join(words)})")
df['category'] = ext[0].map(mapping_dict)
print(df)
                       text   category
0  SuperB Vesterbro T 74637  Groceries
1         Rent        45228    Housing
2  Superbest          86125  Groceries
```

Comment: @Mathias Lund no problemo hope this worked with your data frame